# check if a user-defined type exists before dropping it

Tags: sybase, sybase-ase-15.7

The `sp_droptype` procedure can be used to drop a User Defined Type.

So I have a number of such `sp_droptype` calls in my "clean" script which I invoke using `sqsh -i`. However it is not possible to conditionally invoke `sp_droptype` only if the type does in fact exist or to instruct it to be silent if the type doesn't exist.

Is there a way to test if a type exists or not and only invoke `sp_droptype` if it actually exists? This would result in cleaner output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works the same as in SQL Server; use the following style of construct:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyObject') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_droptype 'dbo.MyObject';
END
```

`OBJECT_ID(...)` returns an integer representing the [object_id from sysobjects](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1570/html/blocks/X57246.htm) for every object stored in the current database.  It will return NULL if the object does not exist.

Another way of testing for object existence:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM systypes st WHERE st.name = 'MyType')
BEGIN
   EXEC sp_droptype 'MyType';
END
```

I don't have the ability to create a type in ASE at the current time, so I cannot say for certain if `OBJECT_ID()` will work.

Comment: this returns NULL for all my user defined types. Maybe it's the `systypes` table? I can see my types in that table but there are more types in there (e.g. `bit`, `char`, `date`). How do I tell them apart?

Comment: I added another way to see if the type exists to my answer.  Unfortunately, I'm not at my ASE instance at the present time.